# Rounding a field

Tags: acumatica

We have a customer who has requested to have the "Duration" or "End Time" field rounded up to the nearest quarter hour in Service Appointment entry (whichever makes the most sense) [Service Appointment Entry screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR2PB.jpg)

With the service appointments there's alot going on. Does anyone have any thoughts on where would be the best way to approach this? There are a lot of events going on that modify the duration and end time and I wouldn't want to have to modify all of them. I'm wondering if its possible to just modify something on the DAC to automatically round the end time up to the quarter hour.

---

Got Pretty far with modifying the DAC. No errors in the code and as I step through it I can see its rounding the time like I want it to. However the field isnt setting in the screen. Am i missing something silly?

```cs
namespace PX.Objects.FS
{
    public class FSAppointmentDetServiceExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.FS.FSAppointmentDetService>
   // public class FSAppointmentDetServiceExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.FS.FSAppointmentDetService>
  {
   #region ActualDateTimeEnd
        [PXDBDateAndTime(UseTimeZone = true, PreserveTime = true, DisplayNameDate = "Actual Date End", DisplayNameTime = "Actual Time End - Nicole")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actual Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        public virtual DateTime? ActualDateTimeEnd
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ActualDateTimeEnd;
            }

            set
            {

                   this._ActualDateTimeEnd = RoundUp(value, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

            }
        }

#pragma warning disable PX1026 // Underscores cannot be used in DAC declarations
  public DateTime? _ActualDateTimeEnd;
#pragma warning restore PX1026 // Underscores cannot be used in DAC declarations

        public static DateTime? RoundUp(DateTime? dt, TimeSpan d)

        {

            DateTime nt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
            if (nt != null)
            {
                return new DateTime((nt.Ticks + d.Ticks - 1) / d.Ticks * d.Ticks, nt.Kind);

            }
            else
            {
                return nt;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if its possible to just modify something on the DAC to
>   automatically round the end time up to the quarter hour.

Yes this is possible and I would recommend it since it's the easiest (perhaps not best) approach.

Create a DAC extension in CODE section, override (replace) the field dates you need to round. Add a backing field to the property and modify the setter property to round the time.

Example:

```
[PXDBDateAndTime(UseTimeZone = true, PreserveTime = true, DisplayNameDate = "Actual Date Time Begin", DisplayNameTime = "Actual Start Time")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actual Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
public virtual DateTime? ActualDateTimeBegin 
{ 
   get { return _ActualDateTimeBegin; }
   set 
   {
      _ActualDateTimeBegin = RoundTime(value);
   }
}

public DateTime? _ActualDateTimeBegin;

public DateTime? RoundTime(DateTime? dateTime)
{
   // return the rounded datetime
}
```